# How Can I capitalize every new letter that appears in typewriting animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would love my typewriting animation to have a capital letter effect at the very end of the animation text. More broadly, I want every new letter that appears to be capitalized.
My code:

```
<div class="typewriter">
  <h5 data-end="g">Example text to test</h5>
</div>
<style>
    .typewriter h5 {
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange;
  }
}

</style>
```

Comment: Is `text-transform: uppercase` what you're looking for?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti Probably it is, but How can I implement this?

Comment: apply it to the `.typewriter h5`-selector: `.typewriter h5 { text-transform: uppercase; }`

Comment: I did it but it changes all letters to uppercase not particular one in the end of letter that appears

Comment: Do yo mean that every new letter should be uppercase and then the old ones go back to lower case?

Comment: The particular letter in the end of the letter? I don't understand

Comment: @Ki Exactly. Thats what I want.

Comment: It seems very hard to implement such a thing as what you want but I suggest using third-party tools to achieve this option.